# MapQuest Leaflet Api - Get optimized path with time and distance

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapquest

I'm using **MapQuest Leaflet Api** to draw a route with multiple stops (Custom Markers). Everything is almost done. I'm getting a route multiple markers and a poly line.

I have two question

1. How to draw a **optimized route onClick of

       button**  code for route optimization is something like this

> ```
> dir = MQ.routing.directions();
>            dir.optimizedRoute({
>                 locations: [
>                    '33.703507, 73.053702',
>                       '33.714328, 73.050625',
>                       '33.730497, 73.077898',
>                       '33.732863, 73.088078'
>                 ]
>             });
> ```

2. How to get distance of total route and time for driving?

My code is given below

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
                var map,
                    dir;
                var custom_icon,
                    marker;
                map = L.map('map', {
                    layers: MQ.mapLayer(),
                    center: [40.045049, -105.961737],
                    zoom: 7
                });

                dir = MQ.routing.directions();
                dir.route({
                    locations: [
                      '33.703507, 73.053702',
                      '33.714328, 73.050625',
                      '33.730497, 73.077898',
                      '33.732863, 73.088078'
                    ],
                    options: { avoids: ['toll road'] }
                });
    CustomRouteLayer = MQ.Routing.RouteLayer.extend({
                        createStopMarker: function (location, stopNumber) {


                            custom_icon = L.divIcon({
                                iconSize: [26, 36],
                                popupAnchor: [0, -18],
                                html: '<span class="notification">' + stopNumber + '</span>'
                            });
                            marker = L.marker(location.latLng, { icon: custom_icon }).bindPopup(location.adminArea5 + ' ' + location.adminArea3).openPopup().addTo(map);

                            marker.on('click', onMarkerClick);

                            return marker;
                        }
                    });
     map.addLayer(new CustomRouteLayer({
                    directions: dir,
                    fitBounds: true,
                    draggable: false,
                    ribbonOptions: {
                        draggable: false,
                        ribbonDisplay: { color: '#CC0000', opacity: 0.3 },
                        widths: [15, 15, 15, 15, 14, 13, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
                    }
                }));
     }
    </script>
    <body style='border:0; margin: 0'>
        <div id='map' style='position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%;'></div>
    </body>
```

Please help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That button will call a function with the MQ.routing.directions.optimizedRoute() code in it.

```
function optimize() {
  dir = MQ.routing.directions();

  dir.optimizedRoute({
    locations: [
      'syracuse ny',
      'springfield ma',
      'ithaca ny',
      'hartford ct'
    ]
  });

  map.addLayer(MQ.routing.routeLayer({
    directions: dir,
    fitBounds: true
  }));
}
```

To get the mileage, use the success event to get to the whole directions response.

```
dir = MQ.routing.directions()
  .on('success', function(data) {
     console.log(data.route.distance);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working perfectly. data.route.distance will distance in meters or kilometers? and data.route.time will give time in minutes or seconds ?

Comment: why this code runs twice? First time it gives exact values and next time it gives undefined .. dir = MQ.routing.directions()
  .on('success', function(data) {
     console.log(data.route.distance);
  });  @MQBrian

Comment: The second time it runs is from the routeshape request. You can check for the object in the response before further processing of it. Distance by default is in miles but the units parameter can be changed in the options. Time is in seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MQBrian

Comment: Is there any way to clear route and markers before drawing optimized route? Please help

Comment: Here is the quick and dirty way I did it.

`mqrl = MQ.routing.routeLayer({
 directions: dir,
 fitBounds: true
});
map.addLayer(mqrl);
setTimeout(function(){map.removeLayer(mqrl)}, 5000);`